# using GPIO to control raspberry picamera with push button

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, gpio

```
import time
import os
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(23 , GPIO.IN)

while True:
if GPIO.input(23)==1:
    os.system('raspistill -o image.jpg')
    os.system(‘gpicview image.jpg &’)
    sleep(20)
    os.system(‘killall gpicview’)
else:
    print "Ready to take picture"
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Dear friends I'm trying to control raspberry picamera with a button.. like when i press the button it should take a picture. I configured GPIO pins also button when I press button nothing is working, however picamera taking photo itself. How can i make it work with button? any experts on python can guide me? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hardware doesn't give us a clean 1 or 0, it bounces back and forth a bit.  Check this code for "debouncing" the button:

https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/robot/buttons_and_switches/