# Using python on RPi to start gpicview & display Image

Tags: python, image, cmd, raspbian

I am using a Raspberry B+ with Raspbian. Having found this reference
( [using GPIO to control raspberry picamera with push button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22254610/using-gpio-to-control-raspberry-picamera-with-push-button) )
to using GPicView, I managed to get a jpeg image to display using the LXTerminal with a ' sudo python jukebox.py -g ' command but the following Errors appeared on the LXTerminal:

> (gpicview:3125): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-scrolled-window-placement after class was initialised
>
> (gpicview:3125): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-button-images after class was initialised
>
> (gpicview:3125): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-label-select-on-focus after class was initialised

The python code is:

> oxmp = Popen(['gpicview', 'Media/fond.jpg'])

I used ' oxmp ' as that is what I used to show a video using omxplayer without any errors.

The GPicView did not open fully but I imagine there is a way to ensure that happens.

I am a novice in Python but an amateur in programming & want to use GPIOs to control a "Question & Answer" screen display. The idea is that the RPi & Screen are switched on at the mains then, after booting, the initial Image will stay on the Screen until a Visitor presses a Button for a Question. There are Images & Videos associated with each Question, depending on the Answer. After 30s of inactivity the initial Image will be displayed.

I am confident I can control the Display with Python but would appreciate pointers on:

1. the correct Command for gpicview to display in the full screen without the Errors;
2. an initial Command after the Boot has finished that will trigger the Python programme to start & display the initial Image - I have just seen a link that I will try;
3. a recharging system for a small battery so that, when the mains is switched off, the RPi closes down automatically.

I have looked at PiPresents-next but have got stuck.

Thanks, in advance, for any help.
Walter

Comment: Those aren't errors, they are warnings. If it works as you intended then I think it's fine. I tend to see similar errors with production applications.

Comment: As an extra how do I close down the gpicview Display ?